# Angular directive that uses dynamic value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am trying to write a simple json pretty-printer directive in angular.js. I have:

```
(function(_name) {
    function prettyJson() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '',
            link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
                console.log($element.text());

                //$element.html(angular.toJson(angular.fromJson($element.text()), true));
            }
        };
    }

    angular
        .module('ourApp')
        .directive(_name, prettyJson);
})('prettyJson');
```

In my view I am doing:

```
<pretty-json>{{ auth.get() }}</pretty-json>
```

The problem is that `console.log($element.text())` comes back as `{{ auth.get() }}` not the angular compiled result of the function call `auth.get()`.

How do I make the directive use the result of the function call `auth.get()`?

Comment: Did you try transclude:true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would swap to using an attribute directive and use the `$attr.$observe()` function to set up a `$watch`-like mechanism that will call a listener function every time the interpolated value of the attribute changes.

The directive code:

```
(function(_name) {
    function _directive() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
                $attr.$observe(_name, function (json) {
                  $element.text(angular.toJson(angular.fromJson(json), true));
                });
            }
        };
    }

    angular
        .module('ourApp')
        .directive(_name, _directive);
})('prettyJson');
```

Usage in markup:

```
<pre pretty-json="{{ auth.get() }}"></pre>
```

See my [Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ms0OVVvgB046pv0b4In8?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass the content you want to format in as a parameter to your directive. e.g.:

JS

```
(function(_name) {
    function prettyJson() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                prettyJson: '='
            },
            template: '<pre>{{prettyJson | json}}</pre>',
        };
    }

    angular
        .module('ourApp')
        .directive(_name, prettyJson);
})('prettyJson');
```

HTML

```
<pretty-json="auth.get()"></pretty-json>
```